# C++ Builder В строке, состоящей из групп нулей и единиц, разделенных пробелами, найти количество групп с пятью цифрами

Tags: c++, c++builder

Прошу помощи. Посмотрите код. Что-то не то:

```
 {
         int word,let,str,i;
    word=0;
    let = 0;
    str= ListBox1->ItemIndex;
    String st=ListBox1->Items->Strings[str];
    for (i= 1; i<st.Length();i++) // Идем по строке

         if(st[i]!=' ')  // если не пробел считаем символ
         let++;
         if(let==5&&st[i+1]==' ')     //если пять  символов и следующий 
                                       пробел считаем слово
            let=0;                    // сбрасываем счетчик букв
            word++;
    Edit2->Text=IntToStr(word);
```

}

Comment: У вас в теле цикла одно условие, а похоже нужно два. Можно 1. или применить `{}` что б обозначить тело цикла  2. или поставить перед вторым `if` ключевое `else` что б второй if попал в тело.

Comment: Не помогает. Ответ в любом случае выводиться единица

Comment: У вас не правильно записано тело цикла. Покажите 1. Исправленый вариант.  2. Входные данные. 3. Выходные данные.

Comment: Ввожу "1111 11111 1111 11111"                                                          
         void __fastcall TForm1::ListBox1Click(TObject *Sender)
{

        int word,let,str,i;
        word=0;
        let = 0;
        str= ListBox1->ItemIndex;
        String st=ListBox1->Items->Strings[str];
        for (i= 1; i<st.Length();i++) /

             if(st[i]!=' ')  
                let++;
             else
                 if(let==5 && st[i+1]==' ')   
                let=0;                    
                word++;
   Вывод "1"

Comment: А во втрором if у вас что? let = 0 и всё? Цикл вхолостую отработал, за циклом у вас word++ поэтому ответ у вас 1.

Comment: `for (i= 1; i<st.Length();i++){
             if(st[i]!=' '){  
                let++;
                if(let==5 && st[i+1]==' ') 
                let=0;                    
                word++;}
        Edit2->Text=IntToStr(word);}` Во втором 'if' let=0 - сбрасывается счетчик для символов, если выполнены условия , пять  символов подряд и далее пробел. И word++ считает это как один блок

Comment: Так тоже не верно, лучше вернуть на шаг назад, и ещёраз проанализировать алгоритм. Данный вариант даст вам st.Length()-1 всегда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int f(String str)
{
  int wordCount = 0;

  while(str.Pos(" "))
  {
    int curPos = str.Pos(" ");

    if(curPos == 6)
    {
      ++wordCount;
    }

    str = str.SubString(curPos + 1, str.Length() - curPos);
  }

  if(str.Length() == 5)
    return ++wordCount;

  return wordCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто не нужно избегать фигурных скобок...

```
for (i= 1; i<st.Length();i++) // Идем по строке
{
   if(st[i]!=' ')  // если не пробел считаем символ
   {
     let++;
   }

   if(let==5&&st[i+1]==' ')     //если пять  символов и следующий 
   {                              пробел считаем слово
      let=0;                    // сбрасываем счетчик букв
      word++;
   }
}
```

И при подсчете слов учесть, что в конце строки нет пробела.

Comment: `if(let==5&&(st[i+1]==' ' || st[i+1] == "/0"))` Такая логика подойдет для окончания строки?

Comment: Если в реализации String признаком конца строки является /0, то да.

Comment: `int word,let,str,i;
        word=0;
        let = 0;
        str= ListBox1->ItemIndex;
        String st=ListBox1->Items->Strings[str];
        for (i= 1; i<st.Length();i++){
             if(st[i]!=' '){                
                let++;
                }
                if(let==5 && (st[i+1]==' '|| st[i+1]=='\0'))
                {                     
                let=0;                     
                word++;
                }
                }
                Edit2->Text=IntToStr(word);
}` с таким кодом получается следующее

Comment: если я ввожу 11111 11111 111 ответ 2, если 11111 111 11111 111 ответ 1, если 11111 ответ 0. Что-то я не учитываю. Подскажите где я что не вижу.

Comment: При вводе 11111 ответ 0, вы как минимум не читаете последний символ  for(i = 1; i **<=** st.Length(); i++).

Comment: Если находится знак пробела, но let != 5, то все сразу ломается, поэтому во втором случае выводит ответ 1, так как учитывается только первые пять единиц.

Comment: for(i = 1; i <= st.Length(); i++) при таком написание выскакивает ошибка памяти

Comment: Конечно, на последнем шаге st[i+1] пытается получить доступ к чужой памяти. Используйте методы класса String типа: 
int __fastcall AnsiPos(const AnsiString& subStr) const
int __fastcall Pos(const AnsiString& subStr) const

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду что то типа этого `for (i= 1; i<st.AnsiPos('\0');i++)`

Comment: Что-то я вообще запутался